# Is it possible to disable OTHER programs that have hooked the Windows Clipboard with ChangeClipboardChain

Tags: winapi, vsto, clipboard

I have an application that inserts lots of text in Word documents using the clipboard as the intermediary. I either do that with the usual Paste command in VSTO, or various other API calls that indirectly do the same thing. I do not control everything being inserted, so I cannot just use [Range.InsertFragment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226143(v=office.12).aspx) or another alternative.

On some machines, users have applications that hook the clipboard to do other cool things, such as saving a clipboard stack, etc. For example, I use and love [ArsClip](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97) to give me access to the last 50 things I put in the clipboard, and it exhibits the problem. There are lots of other similar utilities.

Most of the time, I believe thse programs use [ChangeClipboardChain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649034(v=vs.85).aspx) to hook the clipboard, but I'm not certain if there are other ways to do it.

I have always had some problem if certain other programs are running, and the problem became much more acute with Office 2016.

- For earlier versions of Office, the symptom would be that the .Paste operation would fail after a fairly length timeout, and it happened but sporadically enough to mostly ignore.
- For Office 2016, you get the same long delay, and then an error that says "The action was blocked by organization policy", and the frequency increased by an order of magnitude.

I usually have to mitigate this by searching for the offending program and killing it, but that's obviously a losing long-term strategy.

So does anyone know of a way to *temporarily* disable the clipboard chain so the clipboard monitoring is disabled, and then restore it to just the way it was.

As an alternative, is there a way to at least walk the stack of viewers and see if there are any known problem children, and shut them down automatically.

Comment: A clipboard viewer is [not the only way to monitor the clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649016.aspx#dataxchg_Monitoring_Clipboard_Contents) for changes. And there is no way to temporarily disable the viewer chain, or to walk the chain. You need to stop using the clipboard and find another solution.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). The clipboard belongs to the user. Your application is not entitled to trash the user's clipboard. There are many ways to create a temporary store, and allow other parties to stream data to it. And it can be secured, too. Look for a real solution, before users of your software start killing *your* application, so that they can use the system the way it's meant to be used.

Comment: The link in the first reply was useful and I think I might be able to use it. I strongly suspect I can just hook the chain and then refrain from passing on the message to the rest of the listeners. It might work. I don't trash the clipboard (I save/restore) and I don't own all the code that exhibits the problem, so even if I quit using the clipboard in my code, it only removes about half the problem. There are certain things in VSTO you can only  do through the clipboard, so using the mechanism is very common, and generally acceptable as long as you save/restore.  Thanks for the pointer.